# nginx large static file serving slow on AWS EBS-backed server

Tags: nginx, amazon-web-services, centos

I'm trying to figure out the correct tuning for nginx on an AWS server that is wholly backed by EBS. The basic issue is that when downloading a ~100MB static file, I'm seeing consistent download rates of ~60K/s. If I use scp to copy the same file from the AWS server, I'm seeing rates of ~1MB/s.  (So, I'm not sure EBS even comes into play here).

Initially, I was running nginx with basically the out-of-the-box configuration (for CentOS 6.x).  But in an attempt to speed things up, I've played around with various tuning parameters to no avail -- the speed has remained basically the same.

Here is the relevant fragment from my config as it stands at this moment:

```
location /download {
    root /var/www/yada/update;
    disable_symlinks off;
    autoindex  on;

    # Transfer tuning follows
    aio        on;
    directio   4m;
    output_buffers 1 128k;
}
```

Initially, these tuning settings were:

```
sendfile       on;
tcp_nopush     on;
tcp_nodelay    on;
```

Note, I'm not trying to optimize for a large amount of traffic.  There is likely only a single client ever downloading at any given time.  The AWS server is a 'micro' instance with 617MB of memory.  Regardless, the fact that scp can download at ~1MB/s leads me to believe that HTTP should be able to match or beat that throughput.

Any help is appreciated.

**[Update]**
Additional information.  Running a 'top' command while a download is running, I get:

```
top - 07:37:33 up 11 days,  1:56,  1 user,  load average: 0.00, 0.01, 0.05
Tasks:  63 total,   1 running,  62 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
```

and 'iostat' shows:

```
Linux 3.2.38-5.48.amzn1.x86_64      04/03/2013  _x86_64_    (1 CPU)

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           0.02    0.00    0.03    0.03    0.02   99.89

Device:            tps   Blk_read/s   Blk_wrtn/s   Blk_read   Blk_wrtn
xvdap1            0.23         2.66         8.59    2544324    8224920
```

Comment: Did you find [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7395876/nginx-serving-static-large-file)? It certainly looks similar with the CPU at 100%.

Comment: I did.  But my CPU is completely idle.  I have now set 'sendfile off;' 'aio on;' 'directio 256k;' and my throughput is up to ~130K/s average.  Better, but a long way from 1MB/s.

Comment: First rule out the invisible minions. If you download on the same machine, first via localhost then via it's official hostname, how are the speeds then?

Comment: Locally on the same machine, with the official hostname, HTTP is getting ~15MB/s.

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered turning sendfile on?  [Sendfile](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#sendfile) allows nginx to use the kernel directly to send static files, so it should be faster than any other option.

Answer (score 2):

By default scp will much faster then your HTTP connection. I have a suggestion for you. If you are serving a static file, I prefer to use S3 with Cloud front. Which makes it faster. Its very difficult to achieve better performance there is a file transfer.

Comment: I'm not sure where you base the assumption on that scp will be faster then http. In fact it will be slower by default since things have to be encrypted.

Answer (score 0):

Given that things work well on the same machine you are getting throttled. First check your usage policy with AWS, perhaps it's in the fine print. Alternatively, try different ISP'S. If they all give you 60kB/s you know it's AWS.