# Large files download issue with EKS + NGINX + JETTY

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, jetty, amazon-eks

I'm having trouble with a large file download, 3GB. This is my set up JETTY 9.4 + NGINX (helm chart from https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/) on Kubernetes (AWS EKS). It works for smaller files. With such large files I get a "Failed - network error" on the client side. On the jetty side I get a connection reset by peer exception. On the NGINX side nothing apparent, at least not in the log files.

If I download the file directly from the service, ie using kubectl port-forward, there is no problem. So it looks like it's an issue with either EKS or NGINX. I set the usual NGINX suspects to their recommended values but to no avail.

This is my ingress yaml

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
  namespace: webapps
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/client-max-body-size: "0"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: "0"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-buffering: "off"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-max-temp-file-size: "0"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "false"
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - my.website.com
      secretName: tls-secret
  rules:
    - host: my.website.com
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: servicename
              servicePort: 8080
            path: /
```

I also checked the generated nginx conf and it looks OK.

Any recommendation at what to look at next?

Comment: Have you checked the Ingress Resource Events ?
Is it possible for you to increase the level of logging (see: [Troubleshooting NGINX Ingress Controller](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/troubleshooting/)) ?

Answer (score 0):

can you please try with Nginx ingress annotation to increase **read** and **send** timeout

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "1800" 
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "1800"
```

Comment: Yes, just tried and it fails the same. I forgot to mention it but the error is immediate, ie max a few MB before it fails, ie a few seconds. It was a legitimate idea but I don't think there are timing issues at the moment.

Comment: @Thomas https://stackoverflow.com/a/22605784/5525824

Comment: Not sure which answer you are referring to but I already have nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-max-temp-file-size: "0"